# Loading SPSS files from github

Tags: r, r-haven

I don't understand how to import SPSS files (or .rdata or Stata) files that are hosted on github. I have a repository with some data files [here](https://github.com/sjkiss/CES2015/tree/master/CES2015-phone-release), but using the URL for the sav file in there does not work.

```
library(haven)
ces<-'https://github.com/sjkiss/CES2015/CES2015-phone-release/CES2015_CPS-PES-MBS_complete.sav'
out<-read_sav(ces)
```

Comment: You need to use the raw file address from Github.  This file seems to be here (didn't try loading it): [https://github.com/sjkiss/CES2015/raw/master/CES2015-phone-release/CES2015_CPS-PES-MBS_complete.sav](https://github.com/sjkiss/CES2015/raw/master/CES2015-phone-release/CES2015_CPS-PES-MBS_complete.sav) .   In general, you can click on the "Find file" tab in the Github explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Overview

As @DavidKlotz commented in the OP, you need to copy the URL of the file of interest; not the URL of the page that hosts the file of interest on GitHub.

Copy the URL from either the `Download` button, as shown below, or from the `View Raw` hyperlink and paste it into the `file` argument within the [`haven::read_sav()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/haven/README.html) function in [r](/questions/tagged/r).

[image: SS of GitHub]

```
# load necessary package
library( haven )

# transform GitHub url
# from 'Download' button
# into data frame
df <- read_sav( file = "https://github.com/sjkiss/CES2015/raw/master/CES2015-phone-release/CES2015_CPS-PES-MBS_complete.sav" )

# view the dimensions
dim( df ) # [1] 4202  454

# transform GitHub url
# from 'View Raw' hyperlink
# into data frame
df <- read_sav( file = "https://github.com/sjkiss/CES2015/blob/master/CES2015-phone-release/CES2015_CPS-PES-MBS_complete.sav?raw=true" )

# view the dimensions
dim( df ) # [1] 4202  454

# end of script #
```